# How to call a function parameter inside the array filter in type script.?

Tags: typescript

[image]

I've a filter function like this where I can send the required keyword inside the array object for filtration. Thing is inside the filter i.e option.keyword is being taken as an Object than listen to the keyword parameter passed. I couldn't find any question or resource regarding this.

```
 private _filter(value: string, array: any[], keyword : any): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return array.filter(option => option.keyword.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

I've tried something like this and not working:

```
this._filter(value, this.options, 'option.name'))
-----------------
  private _filter(value: string, array: any[], keyword : any): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return array.filter(option => keyword.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please choose which framework you are targeting; AngularJS, a framework that will be reaching its end of support in December, or Angular, a framework now in its 12th version. Don't use both tags unless the question is about migrating from one to the other. Also, it appears your question is not really about either, so you could leave both out.

Comment: Edited the tags.

Comment: Regarding the question; why aren't you typing `keyword` as `string`, which has a `toLowerCase()` method, rather than `any`, which does not?

Comment: Tried both of those, option.keyword is still being taken as object than listen to the parameter.

Comment: `option.keyword` is a property of `option`, which is an element of the `array`. If you're trying to get the `name` property of `option`, use the bracket syntax: `option[keyword]`, as in the duplicate I will post soon.